# Boolean combination of attributes in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, boolean-logic

I'm using Django to outline the relationship between university courses and high school subject requirements.

So far I have the following models:

> ```
> class Course(models.Model):
>    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    #(e.g. Bachelor of _____)
>    ft_years = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField()    #years of full time study
>
> class Requirement(models.Model):    
>    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)    #(e.g. Mathematics 3)
>    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3)    #(e.g. 70)       
>    percent = models.NullBooleanField()    #True if score is in percent
> ```

My question is, how can I add a Boolean combination of Requirement to each Course?

For example:

> A Bachelor of Physics (Course) has the following Requirements:
>   (70% in Physics) **AND** (50% in Mathematics 3 **OR** 45% in Mathematics 4)

---

*Additional info:* Because several courses may share the same requirement (e.g. 70% in Physics) but each course may have several requirements, I am planning to use a m2m model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a `CompoundRequirement` which has some number of requirements that it `OR`s together (with a `ManyToManyField`) and then each class has some `Requirement`s and some `CompoundRequirement`s. ANDs are handled by having more than one requirement, so all you need to handle is ORs.

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work for "R1 OR (R2 AND R3)", since the nested AND cannot be handled by the Course?

Comment: I am thinking maybe a CompoundANDRequirement class as well?

Comment: depends on how deeply you want the relations to be able to go. I don't really know how to nicely extend this deeply in a database.